# emacs magit doesn't have remote repo straight

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I've got two machines open, pushing and pulling to and from a GitHub repo. On one machine Emacs magit works fine, staging, committing, then pushing or pulling. On the other it keeps failing. For a push it says:

```
remote part of refspec is not a valid name in master:https://github.com/myrepo...[See buffer *magit-process* for details]
```

Doing a push at the command prompt on that same machine works fine, though. It asks for username and password, and completes the push. But then when I try to do a magit pull it asks:

```
Pull branch from remote origin:
```

...and will not take anything I type in, giving me

```
Git failed...[See buffer *magit-process* for details]
```

Again, from terminal the pull works fine. So what could this be? BTW, where is this *magit-process* buffer anyway?

Comment: `*magit-process*` can be accessed from `magit` by pressing `$`. (It's a regular buffer, so you can also switch to it using `C-x b` or whatever you normally use to switch buffers.) Please check your `*magit-process*` and add the error you find there to your question.

Comment: ...and if need be, be sure to use `TAB` to expand the content -- the process buffer(s) in more recent versions of magit are quite enhanced over the old ones.

Comment: Maybe your git config is broken. Try `git config -l` in a shell inside your repo.

Comment: Flagged for deletion because op did not follow up and so this also won't help future visitors.

Comment: @Drew: could you please close this? (Just seen on another question that you can do that.)